Camunda Task List Failure: Filter with id does not exist
Could you please let me know how to overcome with this issue and why I am getting below error and how I can fix it.
Image: camunda error
Failure: Filter with id does not exist
In network call:
{
"type": "InvalidRequestException",
"message": "Filter with id '23124433-2365-55yu-d343-2367ui13434a' does not exist."
}

Try Googling first 'invalidrequestexception camunda' - you provide no context for what you are trying to do.

Can you provide a little more context for this error? What version of Camunda are you using? What were you trying to do, and how did that lead to this error?
